# Animating sprites at random rates

Tags: animation, sprite, directx-9, sprite-sheet

I have a program that displays 5 explosions in a line at the same time. I would like to know how to get each explosion to animate at different rates. Here is the code that actually animates the sprites:

```
//=========================================================================
//
// Helper functions
//
//========================================================================
void Sprite_Draw_Frame(LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9 texture, int destx, int desty, int framenum, int framew, int frameh, int columns)
{
    D3DXVECTOR3 position( (float)destx, (float)desty, 0);
    D3DCOLOR white = D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 255, 255);`

    RECT rect;
    rect.left = (framenum % columns) * framew;
    rect.top = (framenum / columns) * frameh;
    rect.right = rect.left + framew;
    rect.bottom = rect.top + frameh;

    spriteobj->Draw(texture, &rect, NULL, &position, white);
}

void Sprite_Animate(int &frame, int startframe, int endframe, int direction, int &starttime, int delay)
{
    if((int)GetTickCount() > starttime + delay)
    {
        starttime = GetTickCount();

        frame += direction;
        if(frame > endframe) frame = startframe;
        if(frame < startframe) frame = endframe;
    }
}

//============================================================================
//
// Function calls
//
//==============================================================================
```

Tried to use random numbers for the delay variable in `Sprite_Animate` so that the frames would be delayed at different rates. However, the explosions continued to animate in sync.

The `Sprite_Animate` function just updates the global variables `frame` and `starttime` to continue drawing each new frame with the `Sprite_Draw_Frame` function.

```
    //animate and draw the sprite
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Sprite_Animate(frame, 0, 29, 1, starttime, rand() %100);
        Sprite_Draw_Frame(explosion, (i * 100), 100, frame, 128, 128, 6);
    }
```

There is a simple solution to this, and if anyone wants the full code I can send it to you by request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO i figured it out. The reason why they were all in sync even with random `delay` values is because they were all sharing the same global variables `frame` and `starttime`.

So instead, creating a structure of `EXPLOSION` with the member variables `frame` and `starttime` and than using a vector to contain them all. After it just had to be iterated through.

The new code is here in case someone else comes along this problem.

```
//The structue to contain each explosions own frame and starttime variables
struct EXPLOSION
{
    int frame;
    int starttime;
};


//============================================================================
//
// Function calls
//
//==============================================================================

//animate and draw the sprite
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Sprite_Animate(explosions[i].frame, 0, 29, 1, explosions[i].starttime, rand() % 100);
        Sprite_Draw_Frame(explosion, i * 100, 100, explosions[i].frame, 128, 128, 6);
    }
```